# Syntax error INSERT INTO OleDB

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

Estoy intentando lanzar el siguiente código desde un botón y me salta el error de la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código del botón

```
sCmd = "INSERT INTO Vendedores (Password,Grupo) VALUES ('151515',0)"
GestionSql.Launch(sCmd)
```

GestionSql.Launch código: (la línea 55 del error es el ExecuteNonQuery)

```
Public Sub Launch(ByVal value As String)
    Try
        oCommand.CommandText = value
        oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        oCommand.Connection = oConection
        oConection.Open()
        oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    oConection.Close()
    oCommand.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Base de datos: (password tipo texto corto, grupo tipo número)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo el error, con DELETE, SELECT, etc no tengo problemas...

Comment: Creo que su problema es el siguiente: el campo `Password` como tal es una **palabra reservada** por lo tanto coloque `[]` para poder utilizarla asi: `[Password]` creo que esto soluciona su problema, hágalo y me cuenta.

Comment: Te quiero <3 ya funciona, toda la tarde en google y me lo solucionaste en 5 minutos ... :)

Comment: No tengo reputación suficiente, ya lo he intentado

Comment: Para marcar una respuesta como aceptada, no le solicitará la reputación, considere marcar la respuesta, se hace como ve en esta [**imagen**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boXg0.png)

Comment: Me he dado cuenta que con los SELECT no afectan los reservados, es al escribir en la base de datos y al leer no hay problema o es aleatorio el error al usar reservadas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El único problema que tiene es el siguiente:

El campo `Password` como tal es una [palabra reservada](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321266/list-of-microsoft-jet-4-0-reserved-words) por lo tanto coloque corchetes `[]` para poder utilizar dicho campo. `[Password]`

Asi:

```
sCmd = "INSERT INTO Vendedores ([Password],Grupo) VALUES ('151515',0)"
```

Con esto resolverá su problema, Saludos!

> [Palabras Reservadas](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html)